# Converting response NSArray to Object array swift3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

Hi i am able to get response from server for array list. But i dont know how to parse that response in object array [Feed] and send it on on completion handler. My Code is as follows:

```
class FeedsService {

    private var feedsEndPoint: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"

    public func getFeeds(completion: ([Feed]) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(feedsEndPoint, method: .get)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseJSON{ response in
                print("Response \(response.result.value)")

        }
    }
}
```

Feed Model is as follows:

```
class Feed {
    private var title: String
    private var body: String

    init(title:String, body: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
    }

    public func getTitle() -> String {
        return self.title
    }

    public func getBody() -> String {
        return self.body;
    }
}
```

I want to parse this as Feed Array and sent it on completion callback.
I am using Alamofire rest library for loading data from rest server.

Comment: Nobody can answer your question without seeing what your dataset looks like. -1

Comment: i wonder y u downvoted Please check data set here
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    class FeedsService {

    private var feedsEndPoint: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"

    public func getFeeds(completion: @escaping ([Feed]) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(feedsEndPoint, method: .get)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseJSON{ response in
                print("Response \(response.result.value)")
                var feeds = [Feed]()
                if let jsonArray = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
                    for json in jsonArray {
                        if let feed = Feed(json: json) {
                            feeds.append(feed)
                        }
                    }
                    completion(feeds)
                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, update your Feed class:

```
class Feed {
    private var title: String
    private var body: String

    init(title:String, body: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
    }

    init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        guard let title = json["title"] as? String,
            let body = json["body"] as? String else {
                return nil
        }
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
    }

    public func getTitle() -> String {
        return self.title
    }

    public func getBody() -> String {
        return self.body;
    }
}
```

Just change "title" and "body" to whatever is the appropriate key in your json response.

As **El Tomato** is pointing out that Feed init is not working, this is a test code that can be tried out in a playground:

```
let testFeedJson = ["title": "Test Title", "body" : "Test Body"]
if let testFeed = Feed(json: testFeedJson) {
    print(testFeed.getTitle())
    print(testFeed.getBody())
}
```

Comment: You are not intializing Feed to create an instance of feeds.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Feed instance is created here: `if let feed = Feed(json: json) {feeds.append(feed)}`

Comment: Check the updated answer (at the bottom) and please try the Feed class in the playground. Please, tell me what is wrong there before giving me -1.

Comment: Yes checking your answer thanks for response, can u clarify this code
let feeds = response.result.value as! [Feed]
                
                print("Feeds count : \(feeds.count)") It does compile and counts return correct

Comment: I am not sure that `let feeds = response.result.value as! [Feed]` will create an array of `Feed` objects. Server is returning an array of [String:Any] objects. You have to iterate through that array and create `Feed` object from `[String:Any]` object. Can you try the code I suggested in my answer?